# Find where 1 condition a is positive and condition b negative

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

first time posting, I've done a search but don't seem to be able to find what I'm looking for.

I'm using Rails 5 and trying to search my db with 2 conditions, the problem I'm having however is that one of my conditions is a negative, I can't find out how to get this to work.

Currently I have this:

```
Case.where({source: 'online', status: 'working'})
```

I want to find cases where the `source` is 'Online' and the `status` is **not** 'Working'

The above finds all cases where the source is Online and the status is Working. I tried the below but that doesn't seem to work.

```
Case.where({source: 'online', status: !'working'})
```

Can anyone help me with this, or point me in the direction of documentation?

Comment: This is all very well documented http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `where.not` condition:

```
Case.where(source: 'online').where.not(status: 'working')
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't release you could chain them together. That's great. Still quite a new developer :)